# Watching YouTube videos in command line failed

Tags: raspbian

I am running **Raspbian** and tried the below command to watch Youtube videos in the command line mode

```
yt --player omxplayer
```

But I got the below error message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/yt", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('whitey==0.3', 'console_scripts', 'yt')()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/whitey-0.3-py2.7.egg/yt/__init__.py", line 31, in main
    ui.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/whitey-0.3-py2.7.egg/yt/__init__.py", line 84, in run
    curses.wrapper(self._curses_main)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/curses/wrapper.py", line 43, in wrapper
    return func(stdscr, *args, **kwds)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/whitey-0.3-py2.7.egg/yt/__init__.py", line 127, in _curses_main
    self._update_screen()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/whitey-0.3-py2.7.egg/yt/__init__.py", line 185, in _update_screen
    self._add_table_row(self._help, 0, 0, w-1, self._bar_attr, max_width=16, win=self._help_bar)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/whitey-0.3-py2.7.egg/yt/__init__.py", line 362, in _add_table_row
    win.addstr(y, x, truncate('%s:%s' % (k,v), min(w-x, cell_w)).encode(self._code), attr)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2026' in position 12: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I followed the correct steps to install all the software package

```
    sudo apt-get install omxplayer
    sudo apt-get install youtube-dl
    sudo youtube-dl -U
    sudo youtube-dl --update
    sudo apt-get install python-setuptools
    sudo easy_install whitey
```

my youtube-dl is the latest version.
I still cannot run the yt program.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [this tutorial](http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?t=8157).  Here is what I think you need to do:

> Navigate to whitey's `/src/yt/` directory, and edit `__init__.py` (your path to that file is `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/whitey-0.3-py2.7.egg/yt/__init__.py`). 
>   The line that has the mplayer command in it, change `mplayer` to
>   `omxplayer`, and remove the argument switches. Or you could just
>   replace that file with [this one](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/33311875/__init__.py).

Other than that, your installation process worked fine for me, so I'm not sure what you did wrong.

Answer (score 1):

your python script tripped over an UTF8 characters in the youtube video file name or title.

you should try something else that has **ascii-only** characters in the title/name and see if your installation works, then you may proceed to fix it for international characters by contacting the author of the original script or by fixing it yourself.